# How to call a function after an asynchronous for-loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following `for-loop`:

```
for await (const account of accountCursor) {
  const newAccount = handleAccount(account, migrationService);
  try {
    await migrationService.accountService.create(newAccount);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Unable to create account');
    throw Error(error)
  }
}

handleRelatedAccounts();  // call once the for-loop has completed
```

Once it has finished, I want to call another function. Since it is asynchronous, how can I call the function **after** the `for-loop` has finished, not during?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to run the function whether or not an error is caught and re-thrown in your loop, you can just wrap the entire loop in a [`try...finally`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) statement: below is an example. (If not, I'm not sure why you are re-throwing the caught error and what kind of behavior you expect.)

```js
try {
  for await (const account of accountCursor) {
    const newAccount = handleAccount(account, migrationService);
    try {
      await migrationService.accountService.create(newAccount);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Unable to create account');
      throw Error(error)
    }
  }
}
finally {
  handleRelatedAccounts();  // call once the for-loop has completed
}
```

Comment: From one Jackson to another (I'm assuming that's what *jcksn* is supposed to mean), thank you. I completely forgot about `finally{}`.

Comment: @JakeJackson It does :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to do anything. `handleRelatedAccounts();` always run after the loop. `await` means it will wait until the premise is finished to do the next code.
Because you `throw Error(error)`, it will stop the execution when there is an exception, `handleRelatedAccounts();` will be never hit in this case.